# Responsive menu - reducing margin on resize

Tags: html, css, navigation, responsive-design

I'm trying to set up my horizontal menu so that it will 'squeeze' my navigation items together until the space between them has been used up, keeping an even space between each one as it reduces.

Once it gets to the point that the items are too close together my media query will kick in to re-arrange the menu.

I'm having trouble creating the 'squeezing' behaviour though. As soon as the window size is reduced, rather than squeezing my nav items up it's pushing them onto two lines.

Is there any way to get around this behaviour with just HTML and CSS?

Here's what i'm doing so far:

```
<nav id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Menu item1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu item2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu item3</a></li>        
        <li><a href="#">Menu item4</a></li>
        <li class="last"><a href="#">Menu item5</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

And the CSS:

```
#menu ul, #menu li { 
    margin:0; 
    padding:0; 
    list-style-type:none; 
}

#menu li { 
    float:left; 
    margin-right:4%; 
}
```

I've also put this into a fiddle so you can see what I mean - http://jsfiddle.net/q3gjg/. I don't want the items pushed onto two lines until there is no horizontal space left between them.

(I know this could be done using a series of media queries that reduced the margin between the items in steps, but this would result in a lot of media queries and doesn't seem very elegant).

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a different approach. Don't use margins in this instance, use width and percentage.

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/q3gjg/1/

```
#menu li { 
    float:left; 
    display: block;
    width: 20%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

**EDITED**

You state you do not wish to use media queries due to the amount you would need, but in this instance you would only need 2

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/q3gjg/3/

```
@media (max-width: 440px) {
   #menu li { margin-right:2%;} 
}
@media (max-width: 400px) {
   #menu li { margin-right:0;} 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is actually what I was doing before. The problem with this is that because my navigation items vary in length it was creating uneven spaces. For example 'About' had a large gap either side, whereas 'Photography' had a smaller gap. If there's no other way it will have to do, but I would like another solution if there is one.

Answer (score 4):

You can try using `display: table-cell;` to your list rather using `float: left;`

```
#menu li {   
    padding-right:4%; 
    display: table-cell;
    width: 200px; /* give here your menu width */
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/q3gjg/2/)